# opengl create a depth_stencil texture for reading

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm using defered rendering in my application and i'm trying to create a texture that will contain both the depth and the stencil.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height, 0,
???, GL_FLOAT, 0);
```

Now what format enum does opengl want for this particular texture. I tried a couple and got error for all of them

Also, what is the correct glsl syntax to access the depth and stencil part of the texture. I understand that depth texture are usually uniform sampler2Dshadow. But do I do

```
float depth = texture(depthstenciltex,uv).r;// <- first bit ? all 32 bit ? 24 bit ?
float stencil = texture(depthstenciltex,uv).a;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Now what format enum does opengl want for this particular texture.

The problem you are running into is that Depth+Stencil is a totally oddball combination of data. The first 24-bits (depth) are fixed-point and the remaining 8-bits (stencil) are unsigned integer. This requires a special packed data type: `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8`

> Also, what is the correct glsl syntax to access the depth and stencil part of the texture. I understand that depth texture are usually uniform sampler2Dshadow.

You will actually ***never*** be able to sample both of those things using the same sampler uniform and here is why:

> #### [OpenGL Shading Language 4.50 Specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf#page=164)  -  ***8.9 Texture Functions***  -  p. 158
>
> > For depth/stencil textures, the sampler type should match the component being accessed as set through the OpenGL API. When the depth/stencil texture mode is set to `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`, a floating-point sampler type should be used. When the depth/stencil texture mode is set to `GL_STENCIL_INDEX`, an unsigned integer sampler type should be used. Doing a texture lookup with an unsupported combination will return undefined values.

This means if you want to use both the depth and stencil in a shader you are going to have to use texture views (OpenGL 4.2+) and bind those texture to two different Texture Image Units (each view have a different state for `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_TEXTURE_MODE`). Both of these things together mean you are going to need at least an OpenGL 4.4 implementation.

#### Fragment shader that samples depth and stencil:

```c
#version 440
// Sampling the stencil index of a depth+stencil texture became core in OpenGL 4.4

layout (binding=0) uniform sampler2D  depth_tex;
layout (binding=1) uniform usampler2D stencil_tex;

in vec2 uv;

void main (void) {
  float depth   = texture (depth_tex,   uv);
  uint  stencil = texture (stencil_tex, uv);
}
```

#### Create a stencil view texture:

```c
// Alternate view of the image data in `depth_stencil_texture`
GLuint stencil_view;
glGenTextures (&stencil_view, 1);
glTextureView (stencil_view, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth_stencil_tex,
               GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, 0, 1, 0, 1);

// ^^^ This requires `depth_stencil_tex` be allocated using `glTexStorage2D (...)`
//       to satisfy `GL_TEXTURE_IMMUTABLE_FORMAT` == `GL_TRUE`
```

#### OpenGL state setup for this shader:

```c
// Texture Image Unit 0 will treat it as a depth texture
glActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture   (GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth_stencil_tex);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_TEXTURE_MODE, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT);

// Texture Image Unit 1 will treat the stencil view of depth_stencil_tex accordingly
glActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture   (GL_TEXTURE_2D, stencil_view);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_TEXTURE_MODE, GL_STENCIL_INDEX);
```

Comment: Probably a workaround is creating a texture view of the original texture, and set a different `GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_STENCIL_MODE` for the view.

Comment: @peppe: Thank you for your suggestion. I had that thought too but then I foolishly thought that wouldn't work because `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8` is not a member of `GL_VIEW_CLASS_32_BITS`. However, since the internal formats of both textures ***exactly*** match that does not matter. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman This is an old topic, but may be you could help me? In case I don't want to access stencil values in shader, but use stencil regularly as a mask, how should I work with stencil attachment? Here is what I tried - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504028/how-to-use-depth-texture-with-stencil-opengl-es-3-0. Will appreciate any comment, thanks

Comment: I guess you included it just for clarity, but the line `glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_STENCIL_MODE, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT);` can be omitted, since the initial value of `GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_STENCIL_MODE` is `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`.

Comment: this shader code won't compile in later versions. In `#version 460`, calling `texture()` on a `sampler2D` always returns a `vec4`, for a `usampler2D` it will return `uvec4`. I don't know what to do now....

Comment: @neo-mashiro I made a complete guess at it in my code, since it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, but `uint stencilBits = texture(texture0, coord).r;` does seem to pull out the actual stencil byte (assuming `texture0` is a `usampler2D` that contains the depth/stencil texture, and `GL_STENCIL_INDEX` is enabled.) For what it's worth, the `.g` and `.b` properties seem to both consistently be 0, while `.a` seems to consistently be 255. I don't know if I'd trust those last values to be consistent across hardware, but `.r` seems to be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

nvm found it

```
glTexImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, w,h,0,GL_DEPTH_STENCIL,
GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8, 0);
```

uint24_8 was my problem.

usage in glsl (330):

```
sampler2D depthstenciltex;
...
float depth = texture(depthstenciltex,uv).r;//access the 24 first bit, 
//transformed between [0-1]
```

Comment: Actually, only the first 24 bits are available for you, the other (stencil) bits are undefined. The initial value of `GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_STENCIL_MODE` property of a texture is `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`, so you can sample the depth component of your combined depth/stencil texture without changing any parameter of your texture object. If you would want to sample the stencil index of your combined depth/stencil texture, then you could set the texture's `GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_STENCIL_MODE` to `GL_STENCIL_INDEX` just like @Andon showed you in his answer.