# Using `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8` with `glTexImage2D`

Tags: opengl

According to the [wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_type) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535727/opengl-create-a-depth-stencil-texture-for-reading), it should be possible to use the enums `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8` and `GL_FLOAT_32_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8_REV` with `glTexImage2D` to upload image data for packed depth stencil formats, but according to the [reference pages](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml), these types are not supported by that function (they are listed in the opengl es reference pages).

Is this a mistake in the reference pages, or is it not possible to use these formats for pixel upload? If so, is there a way to upload to this type of texture (other than rendering to it)?

Comment: @Rabbid76: No, they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference page is missing information (as it is for `glTexSubImage2D`). And that's not the only missing information. For example, `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_5_9_9_9_REV` isn't listed as a valid `type`, but it *is* listed in the errors section as if it were a valid type. For whatever reason, they've been doing a better job keeping the ES pages updated and accurate than the desktop GL pages.

It's best to look at the OpenGL specification for these kinds of details, especially if you see a contradiction like this.